# How to display a list of items from a reactjs map loop horizontally with wrap?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a list of items (dynamically created buttons) coming from a reactjs map function. I want them listed horizontally and also allow wrapping remaining items to the next line if needed. Can some one please help with this. Given below is my code snippet.

```
return( <div>
            { relevantMessages.map(function(thisQuestion){
                return 
                       <p key={thisQuestion.id}>
                           <button key={thisQuestion.id} onClick={() => this.sendThisMessage(thisQuestion.question)}> 
                                {thisQuestion.title}
                           </button>
                       </p>
                 }, this)
             }
        </div>)
```

Comment: You can play around with the [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), e.g. making each element `inline` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css to align horizontally.

**For example:**

```
return( <div>
            { relevantMessages.map(function(thisQuestion){
                return 
                       <p key={thisQuestion.id} style="display:inline-block;">
                           <button key={thisQuestion.id} onClick={() => this.sendThisMessage(thisQuestion.question)}> 
                                {thisQuestion.title}
                           </button>
                       </p>
                 }, this)
             }
        </div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using span tag instead of p tag in the above code snippet solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an issue with React, but more so with CSS.

What you are probably looking for is something such as flex-box. Check out [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a good tutorial on how to use it.

Or try [flexbox-froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) for a gamified of learning it :)